# Integration by parts in solving Poisson equation

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

In Partial Differential Equations by Evans, page 24,

[image]

from (11) to (13), he changes Laplacian for x to Laplacian for y, but I don't know why this can be done. Can you tell me why? Thanks.

Comment: thanks, i was confused about this too!

Answer (score 2):

Because $\partial_x f(x-y) = - \partial_y f(x-y)$. Thus $\Delta_x f(x-y) = \Delta_y f(x-y)$.